# Click Twitch Avatar of offline user? selenium

Tags: python, selenium

how would I click the avatar of someone who is offline in twitch? If you go to someone who is offline and then click their avatar it will take you to their offline stream instead of the main page.
[Example of someone offline](https://www.twitch.tv/mizkif)

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

op = Options()
op.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\bestg\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\bor")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=op)
driver.get('https://www.twitch.tv/mizkif')

#trying to click the avatar 
stream = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "::before")))
stream.click()
```

Comment: do you get error or what?

Comment: maybe you should create better selector. Code works for me if I use `time.sleep(10)` with `driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[@status='offline']").click()` but not with `driver.find_element_by_link_text("::before").click()` - maybe there are some other chars in text and you need to add it. OR maybe `::before` is not text in link but extra information displayed in `DevTools`.

Answer (score 1):

Code works if I use different selector

```py
.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ".//a[@status='offline']")))
```

`::before` is not text in link. It is CSS selector which shows in  `DevTools` that there is some element created with this selector.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! I need to look into XPATH a bit more and figure out how to use it